# ContainerFromItem() to select GridViewItem from bound object

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, uwp

I have a `GridView` with template set up like this:

```
<GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:SampleModel">
        <Grid Height="112" Padding="12" Width="227">
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                        Text="{x:Bind Description}"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</GridView.ItemTemplate>
```

The `SampleModel` class only has two properties, `Id: int` and `Description: string`. The GridView is now bound to a list of `SampleModel`type. Like this:

```
var list = new List<SampleModel>
{
    new SampleModel { Id = 1, Description = "Apple" },
    new SampleModel { Id = 2, Description = "Orange" },
    new SampleModel { Id = 3, Description = "Banana" }
};
MyGridView.ItemsSource = list;
```

Here is my problem. Another method (which returns a collection of `int` values) implemented in our program throws only the `Id`. If this method returns, for example, `new int[] { 2, 3 }`, how do I get the `GridViewItem` objects bound to Orange and Banana? Here's what I've come up so far, to no avail:

```
var source = MyGridView.DataContext as List<SampleModel>;
foreach (var id in new int[] { 2, 3 })
{
    var fruit = source.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);
    GridViewItem gvi = MyGridView.ContainerFromItem(fruit) as GridViewItem;
    gvi.IsSelected = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you know to use binding for your GridView to show data, then you should also know that binding can do most things for you. In your case, There was no doubt the binding also can help you achieve your target.

You just need to declare an extra property as the each item's background. Then, you could use linq statement to find the specific items from the collection and change their property value.

I just made a code sample for you according to your above code snippet.

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind list}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:SampleModel">
                <Grid Height="112" Padding="12" Width="227" Background="{x:Bind ItemBackground,Mode=OneWay}">
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                    Text="{x:Bind Description}"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
```

```cs
public class SampleModel:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string PropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this,new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName));
        }
    }

    private int _Id;
    public int Id
    {
        get => _Id;
        set
        {
            if (_Id != value)
            {
                _Id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Id");
            }
        }
    }

    private string _Description;

    public string Description
    {
        get =>_Description;
        set
        {
            if (_Description != value)
            {
                _Description = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("Description");
            }
        }
    }

    private SolidColorBrush _ItemBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    public SolidColorBrush ItemBackground
    {
        get => _ItemBackground;
        set
        {
            if (_ItemBackground !=value)
            {
                _ItemBackground = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("ItemBackground");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
private ObservableCollection<SampleModel> list { get; set; }
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        list = new ObservableCollection<SampleModel>
{
new SampleModel { Id = 1, Description = "Apple" },
new SampleModel { Id = 2, Description = "Orange" },
new SampleModel { Id = 3, Description = "Banana" }
}; 
    }
```

```cs
var tem_list = list.Where(x => x.Id == 1|| x.Id == 2).ToList();
foreach (var item in tem_list)
{
     item.ItemBackground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.LightYellow);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you enumerate through the `Items` property, which contains all the Items you have added to your `GridView`?

Like :

```
for (int i = 0; i < MyGridView.Items.Count; i++)
{
    if(MyGridView.Items[i] is SampleModel item && (item.ID == 2 || item.ID == 3))
    {
        var gridViewItem = MyGridView.ContainerFromItem(item);
        /// do something with this GridViewItem
    }
}
```

Comment: I would, but is there any other way to directly access the items? I could be looping a hundred times only to select two.